# Является ли пробел знаком препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Или он имеет другое наименование?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Название у него - пробел.
Если и знак, то орфографический.

Comment: Да. даже термины такие есть - орфограмма-буква, орфограмма-пробел.